# expressionengine 2.x compare two variables against each other inside EE tags

Tags: expressionengine

I have looked through the EE docs and can find

```
if variable operator value
```

However I am trying to do

```
if variable operator variable
```

It doesnt seem to work

I am doing

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="p"}
{if last_segment == company_name}
```

Company name is a field in the channel 'p'

Any one any ideas?

thanks

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, had to add

```
custom_fields="yes"
```

to the exp:channel

Comment: http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#parameters 

custom_fields isn't a parameter of {exp:channel:entries}? You can disable custom fields, but they're all included by default.

Comment: Never saw that parameter in exp:channel:entries. But to respond to your question, Something like this should work: {if "{last_segment}" == "company_name}"}